# What's the relationship between I/O streams with outer devices

Tags: c++, stream

Currently I'm self-learning C++. I get quite confused about the relation between the streams and the outer devices. The cplusplus explanation about the basic I/O is

> There is no need to know details about the media associated to the stream or any of its internal specifications. All we need to know is that streams are a source/destination of characters, and that these characters are provided/accepted sequentially (i.e., one after another).

So what does it mean by "streams are a source/destination of characters".
Take monitor as an example, the destination of the characters shouldn't be the monitor rather than the streams? Or I can just take monitor as an stream? If so then how to understand the follows:

> Output stream objects can write sequences of characters and represent other kinds of data. Specific members are provided to perform these output operations (see functions below).
>   The standard objects cout, cerr and clog are objects of this type.

It is too wired to think of cout,cerr and clog are objects of a monitor...
I rather take the output stream as a different object from the monitor.

Could someone kindly explain to me flatly about what's the true connection between I/O streams and the outer devices and how it works? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The connection you are looking for is implementation-dependent, iostreams is an abstraction as it should be. Under Linux and other Unix OS:es (yes, Linux is a Unix OS, and yes, Linux is an OS, not just a kernel), I have seen iostream variants connected to network sockets (gcc extension around 2003) as well as more normal I/O channels as terminals and vanilla UTF-8/8859-1 text files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Streams in general are objects that represent something that can be thought of as a stream of characters. Open files, standard output, standard input and a lot of others.

There is no stream for "monitor" because no one can say what can your "monitor" do in certain hardware configuration and certain environment.

However, there are such things as "standard input" (`cin`), "standard output" (`cout`) and `cerr`. These streams provide a simple and standard way of communication between your app and the outer world, especially for so called console applications that are run in console and can input and output text. But even a console application still may be run with redirected standard I/O streams, reading from and writing to files (or something else) instead. That's why C++ standard says nothing what do these streams correspond to: the correspondence depends on the environment.

Finally, `cin`/`cout`/`cerr` interface allows you to do only the very basic things. All the advanced communication between your program and the outer world is also environment-dependent and usually requires you to use special libraries (e.g. to implement GUI).

Comment: Thanks for the plain explanation! I think probably I over understood "streams are a source/destination of characters" since I didn't feel any difficulty understanding your words. Thanks for the efforts!

Answer (score 4):

A stream is just an abstraction over a wide class of devices, which have in common the fact that you can write characters in them. The exact implementation depends from the operating system (although on modern OSes C++ streams wrap operating system-provided streams).

The console? You can write characters in it (and have them displayed on screen). A file? You can write characters in it (and have them saved on disk). A serial port? You can write characters on it (and have them transmitted to another computer). A printer? You can write characters on it (and have them printed on paper).

In most cases your code doesn't want to deal with the dark details of how each of those peripherals actually work under the hood or their specific interfaces, you just want to write some characters to some peripheral defined externally; your log format is probably going to be independent from the fact that you are printing its data on the console, on a file or sending it over the network. This is where the "stream abstraction" comes useful.

(the same holds for *input* streams, with the difference that there you can *read* characters)

Of course, when you need to exploit the specificities of each device the stream abstraction gets less useful or even gets in the way. If I need to display graphics on a screen or on a printer a representation such as a series of plain text characters isn't going to cut it.

Comment: Nicely written, +1. Given the OP's mention of monitors, you might want to mention console libraries such as `ncurses`.

Comment: @Matteo Italia But on Cprogramming.com I got another definition about "stream": A 'stream' is internally nothing but a series of characters.

Comment: @Matteo Italia So does it mean different context 'stream' means different thing? Like some context more abstract and some are more concrete like "a series of characters"?

Comment: @Matteo Italia Anyway thanks for the efforts! I got what you mean:-)

Comment: @Des1gnWizard: the exact meaning of "stream" depends from the context, but in general it refers to some abstract thing where characters can be put or taken over. The key point is that it's *abstract* (i.e. it's an interface, hiding the details of the underlying device) and that it only deals with *characters* with some defined ordering. The explanation above is to make more clear where does this abstraction comes from and why it is useful.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Yeah the key is "it's abstract". I finally "generally" got it!

Answer (score 0):

The stream is the interface to the outer device. When you call a stream function it triggers some sw below which takes care of handling the device, i.e. like a driver.

You don't need to worry about what is going on in that software - you only need to learn the stream interface. This level abstraction is very handy as your code is independant of the exact outer device. Others have written sw which makes, e.g. console io, file io, etc. look the same to your code regardless of OS and disk type and monitor type and so on.